# Download a video from blob:https url from eventive

Tags: url, curl, video, ffmpeg

I want to download a video from eventive but the  tag contains a blob url (blob:https://watch.eventive.org/**************).

I have been reading some answers to similar questions but they all assume that the video has a mp3u8 file extension, which in my case doesn't.

I have also tried to directly download that url (removing the blob:) with curl, but I obtained a html code which I cant really understand, which contains a lot of references to javascript files.

Any tip would be really helpful.

Edit:

I have been doing some more tests and I have been able to found a url to a manifest file which points apparently to the video data. I have tried to open that url using VLC and it loads some info about the video, and it even plays it, but the screen is completely black.

I have also tried to download it using ffmpeg but it gives a bunch of errors.

```
ffmpeg -i https://eventiveprod-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/02968382-069a-4f02-ab3b-67c0b5a8d5b7/5f427f2d65a569006ebd326c.ism/manifest\(format\=mpd-time-csf\)  output.mp4
```

ffmpeg output

```
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x556c1e280bc0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x556c1e280bc0] error while decoding MB 34 0, bytestream 41478                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[h264 @ 0x556c1e280bc0] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2ce440] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2ce440] error while decoding MB 34 0, bytestream 22093                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2ce440] concealing 3600 DC, 3600 AC, 3600 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2f9f40] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2f9f40] error while decoding MB 24 0, bytestream 15117                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[h264 @ 0x556c1e2f9f40] concealing 2040 DC, 2040 AC, 2040 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x556c1e333bc0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x556c1e333bc0] error while decoding MB 17 0, bytestream 8716                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[h264 @ 0x556c1e333bc0] concealing 920 DC, 920 AC, 920 MV errors in I frame
[aac @ 0x556c1e3745c0] channel element 2.8 is not allocated
Input #0, dash, from 'https://eventiveprod-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/02968382-069a-4f02-ab3b-67c0b5a8d5b7/5f427f2d65a569006ebd326c.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)':
  Duration: 00:21:18.00, start: 0.066000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1317 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1770930
      id              : 1_V_video_1
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 686 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 904295
      id              : 1_V_video_2
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 495 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 572685
      id              : 1_V_video_3
    Stream #0:3: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 308 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 301036
      id              : 1_V_video_4
    Stream #0:4(en): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 127999
      id              : 5_A_aac_eng_2_127999
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x556c1e392dc0] channel element 2.8 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:4: Invalid data found when processing input                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[h264 @ 0x556c1e3da900] top block unavailable for requested intra mode                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[h264 @ 0x556c1e3da900] error while decoding MB 34 0, bytestream 41478                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[aac @ 0x556c1e392dc0] Reserved bit set.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[aac @ 0x556c1e392dc0] Number of bands (13) exceeds limit (11).                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[h264 @ 0x556c1e3da900] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in I frame
Error while decoding stream #0:4: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x556c1e392dc0] channel element 2.4 is not allocated                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Error while decoding stream #0:4: Invalid data found when processing input                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[aac @ 0x556c1e392dc0] Multiple frames in a packet.
...
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] frame I:1     Avg QP: 4.13  size:   421
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] frame P:32    Avg QP:14.06  size:  1216
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] frame B:96    Avg QP:20.52  size:   306
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  0.6%  0.0%  P16..4:  9.4%  0.3%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:88.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  3.7%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:96.2%  L0:53.5% L1:46.3% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] 8x8 transform intra:13.0% inter:86.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 1.3% 0.8% 0.2% inter: 0.2% 0.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 98%  0%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33%  2% 64%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 18% 42%  3%  1%  1%  2%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 99%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] ref P L0: 86.7%  1.2%  8.8%  3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] ref B L0: 62.7% 35.4%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5588338c2d00] kb/s:127.70
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Your link is un-testable.

Comment: Ill provide the URL ASAP. I thought that it could be a bad idea, as its protected content (siggraph conference video). Probably untestable anyway, as login is required

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: actually I managed to download the video file, but was drm encrypted so couldnt watch it :)

Comment: @jjcasmar Can you please tell how did you get the DRM encrypted video?

Comment: I recorded the screen with OBS. If you meant the video file that I was unavailable to watch, not really, I cant remember what I did